# Adding days to sysdate based off of values in a column

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a manual table based off of a currently built views table. 
The structure of this current table is as follows:

```
ID | Column1 | Column2 | Buffer Days

1  | Asdf    | Asdf1   | 91
2  | Qwert   | Qwert1  | 11
3  | Zxcv    | Zxcv1   | 28
```

The goal is to add a 4th column after Buffer Days that lists the sys date + the number in buffer days

So the outcome would look like:

```
ID | Column1 | Column2 | Buffer Days | Lookout Date

1  | Asdf    | Asdf1   | 91          | 02-Jan-18
```

Answer (score 0):

That requirement smells like a *virtual column* candidate. However, it won't work:

```
SQL> create table test
  2  (id number,
  3   column1 varchar2(10),
  4   buffer_days number,
  5   --
  6   lookout_date as (SYSDATE + buffer_days)  --> virtual column
  7  );
 lookout_date as (SYSDATE + buffer_days)
                  *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-54002: only pure functions can be specified in a virtual column expression
```

Obviously, as SYSDATE is a non-deterministic function (doesn't return the same value when invoked).

Why not an "ordinary" column in existing table? Because you shouldn't store values that are calculated using other table columns anyway. For example, good old Scott's EMP table contains SAL and COMM columns. It doesn't (and shouldn't) contain TOTAL_SAL column (as SAL + COMM) because - when SAL and/or COMM changes, you have to remember to update TOTAL as well.

Therefore, a **view** is what could help here. For example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2  (id number,
  3   column1 varchar2(10),
  4   buffer_days number
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace view v_test as
  2  select id,
  3         column1,
  4         buffer_days,
  5         sysdate + buffer_days lookout_date
  6  from test;

View created.

SQL> insert into test (id, column1, buffer_days) values (1, 'asdf', 5);

1 row created.

SQL> select sysdate, v.* from v_test v;

SYSDATE            ID COLUMN1    BUFFER_DAYS LOOKOUT_DA
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
23.12.2017          1 asdf                 5 28.12.2017

SQL>
```